# shell: rebooting bunch of servers all at the same time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to be able to reboot a bunch of servers all at the same time (in a bash script).
Currently, what I do is something like that:

```
function reboot_servers() {
    echo "Rebooting servers..."
    for server in "${servers[@]}"
    do
        sshpass -p 'password' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$server 'reboot'
    done
}
```

(`servers` is an array of 4 servers, sometimes 8, and in the future probably more)

Now, I am aware that in theory I cannot really have them rebooted all at the **exact** same time, but I'd like it to be as simultaneously as possible, and the above solution is far from optimal for me.
In my current script, if every iteration takes (say) few hundreds milliseconds in average (the ssh login sometimes lags and is unpredictable), the time passed from when the first server launches the `reboot` command until the last one does could amount to seconds, which is completely ineffective.

I should also mention that the clocks in all the servers are synced, and also to give you some context, the above function is being run over and over again in something similar to this;

```
function main() {
    iteration=0

    while true
    do
        echo "------> Iteration $((++iteration)) <------"
        wait_random_time
        reboot_servers
        wait_for_servers

        if bug_reproduced
        then
            echo "Bug was reproduced."
            exit 0
        else
            echo "No reproduction, trying again..."
        fi
    done
}
```

I read a little bit about the `at` command, but I'm not sure how to use it for my benefit here.

Comment: If you put an `&` on the end of your existing command inside the loop, it wouldn't get you to the closest possible thing to simultaneity, but it'd certainly be a lot closer. The answer by grundic would get you even closer than that, though even then there's room for improvement.

Comment: What's the goal here? If you *really* want to bring a whole bunch of systems down concurrently, I'd be looking at NPS hardware.

Comment: Instead of `reboot`, you could use `shutdown -r TIME` and give them all the same time to shutdown.

Comment: @Barmar, what should I put for `TIME`? Remember this is being run in a loop. 
In addition, I want a reboot, not a shutdown.

Comment: @so.very.tired Just pick some time in the future, long enough for the loop to complete before you reach that time. And the `-r` option to `shutdown` makes it reboot.

Comment: You can combine that with the `pssh` suggestion, so the loop will complete quickly.

Comment: How close does it have to be?  Even if they all received the command at the same moment they will have slightly different reboot times.  You could do the whole thing in bash using ssh sockets, and `&` with a PID assignment after each line.  I have some working code for this that I can dig up if OP is interested or doesn't want to use pssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using [`pdsh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdsh), which gave quite impressive results...

```
$> pdsh -l root -w server0[0-3] date "+%T.%3N"
server00: 12:29:45.845
server01: 12:29:45.830
server02: 12:29:45.870
server03: 12:29:45.893
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [parallel-ssh](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh).

Comment: Hmm. It's a reasonable choice of tools, but if the OP **really** wants the timing to be as close as possible, then they'd want every single handshake negotiation to be complete before *any* system gets the command sent. I'm not seeing documentation that that's something parallel-ssh can do (since it only performs the actual handshake as part of a `run_command()` call).